# how to retrieve any Firebird database data type with just Delphi XE2 and Indy10 TIdTCPClient and TIdCmdTCPServer

Tags: delphi, indy10

My program's TIdTCPClient can request and receive string data from my TIdCmdTCPServer, but I need my TIdCmdTCPServer to return any data type from a Firebird database.  How to do this?

Comment: This is a bit too broad without knowing anything about your existing communication protocol, or how its requests/responses operate.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast any type from and to a string. So just add a prefix indicating what type of data you are sending on each transmission.

Something like :

```
send string: "s[Hello World]"
send integer: "i[97]"
send float: 'f[14.25]"
send date: "d[2016-11-02]" 
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say first get your table structure
SELECT RDB$FIELD_NAME
 FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS
 WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME='TABLENAME'

Write the result to a stringlist
Fields : Tstringlist;
Fields.add(fielddef);

And then send the result back via your tcpserver tcpserver.writestream(fields.tostream,0,1)